# Label Style is converting decimal String names to Number

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling, style

The `feature.attributes.fid` returns a `String` value like "9.3210". But on the map, this value is being converted to some number type and on map is showing the value **9.321 (without the 0)**.

```
var contextResource = {
    getLabel: function (feature)
    {
        return feature.attributes.fid;
    }
};

var resourceStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
     label: '${getLabel}'
},{ context: contextResource });
```

I've tried to make things like:

- `return JSON.stringfy(feature.attributes.fid);` On the map it shows with quotes, like "9.3210"
- `return String(feature.attributes.fid);` This still shows 9.321 (without the 0)

Any suggestions to display 9.3210 (without quotes, and with 0) on map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a suggestion from my friend Danilo Viana, solved the problem by overwriting the OpenLayers.Style.createLiteral behavior like this:

```
OpenLayers.Style.createLiteral = function(value, context, feature, property) {
            if (typeof value == "string" && value.indexOf("${") != -1) {
                value = OpenLayers.String.format(value, context, [feature, property]);
                if(isNaN(value) || !value){
                    return value;
                }else{
                    if(value.indexOf('.') !== -1){
                       return parseFloat(value).toFixed(value.split('.')[1].length);
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        };
```

I also made a [pull request in the project repository](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/1397).